# Is there any way to loop through multiple lists and rename the second occurrence?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to loop over through multiple lists and check whether the list has multiple occurrences. If so I want to rename he lists.

I have tried looping over using two for loops but this code works perfectly for single list and not multi list.

```
new_word = [['abc'],['out'],['pqr'],['abc']]

for i in range(len(new_word)-1):
    word_counter = 1
    for j in range(i+1, len(new_word)):
        if new_word[i] == new_word[j]:
            word_counter = word_counter + 1
            new_word[j] = new_word[j] + "_" + str(word_counter)
        if word_counter > 1:
            new_word[i] = new_word[i] + "_1"
```

Expected :

```
[['abc_1'],['out'],['pqr'],['abc_2']]
```

Actual:

```
[['abc'],['out'],['pqr'],['abc']]
```

Comment: Why is it `new_word = [['abc'],['out'],['pqr'],['abc']]` and not `new_word = ['abc', 'out', 'pqr', 'abc']`? Are those inner lists always just a single element containing a string? If not, can you provide an example.

Comment: Yes it is always single element. There are multiple lists of single element.

Comment: The inner lists only have one element? If yes, why are they there (for example why not `new_word = ['abc', 'out', 'pqr', 'abc']`)? Also not only the 2nd occurrence is renamed in your expected output.

Comment: It might make it easier to use python to it's full potential. Try doing `for word in new_word:` then handling each word from there.

Comment: The inner list elements are coming from a file row that is why it is always going to be  a single element correcting to single line from file.

Comment: @user11969158 but why not convert it something more sensible then? `[item[0] for item in new_word]`? Perhaps if you show how `new_word` is created we can see if it could just be a flat list instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit more verbose than the accepted answer, but will scan all
items in the original a list just once. It does not matter the least thing for small lists, (<10000 items) and no critical response time  (i.e. , you don't have to feed this result to a HTTP response several times each second, for example).

```py
from copy import deepcopy


def suffix_repeats(lst):
    result = deepcopy(lst)
    mapping = {}
    for i, item in enumerate(lst):
        mapping.setdefault(item[0], []).append(i)

    for key, positions in mapping.items():
        if len(positions) > 1:
            for j, pos in enumerate(positions, 1):
                result[pos][0] += f"_{j}"
    return result



new_word = [['abc'],['out'],['pqr'],['abc']]

print(suffix_repeats(new_word))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_word = [["abc"], ["out"], ["pqr"], ["abc"]]

for i in range(len(new_word) - 1):
    word_counter = 1
    for j in range(i + 1, len(new_word)):
        if new_word[i] == new_word[j]:
            word_counter = word_counter + 1
            new_word[j] = [new_word[j][0] + "_" + str(word_counter)]
        if word_counter > 1:
            new_word[i] = [new_word[i][0] + "_1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
new_word = [['abc'],['out'],['pqr'],['abc']]

res=[[el[0]] if new_word.count(el)<2 else [el[0]+"_"+str(new_word[:k].count(el)+1)] for k, el in enumerate(new_word)]

print(res)
```

And output:

```py
[['abc_1'], ['out'], ['pqr'], ['abc_2']]
[Program finished]
```

Comment: I need first occurrence to be renamed as _1. Like in this case abc_1 and then the second abc_2.